# How do the additive inverse, and zero vector axioms hold for this set?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am trying to understand how the following axioms hold for a set $V$:

1. Existence of additive identity
2. Existence of additive inverse

Where $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, with addition defined as:

$(u, v) + (x, y) = (u + x + 1, v + y + 1)$

And scalar multiplication defined as:

$\alpha(u,v) = (\alpha u, \alpha v)$

For the existence of the additive identity, define the zero vector $\mathbb{0} = (-1, -1)$:

$(u, v) + (-1, -1) = (u + (-1) + 1, v + (-1) + 1) = (u, v)$

However, when using $(-1, -1)$ as the zero vector for the additive inverse, the property fails:

$(u, v) + (-1)(u, v) = (u - u + 1, v - v + 1) = (1, 1) \ne (-1, -1)$

I know there can only be 1 zero vector for a vector space, and I also know for this particular vector space both these axioms hold, so clearly I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Which tells you that this is not a vector space under those operations...

Comment: Technically, you are looking for $(x,y)$ such that $(u,v)+(x,y)=(-1,-1)$, which leads to $-(u,v) = (-u-2,-u-2)$. But then, if this *were* a vector space, you would necessarily have $(-1)(u,v) = -(u,v)$, and as you note this is not true. So in fact, the axioms do *not* hold. How is it that you "know" that they do?

Comment: Textbook solutions: https://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/LINALG/Linalg_pdf.pdf#page=41&zoom=100,96,92

Comment: So, you want me to look through 196 pages to find out exactly what you are looking at? Rather cavalier of you to link me to a **whole book** and leave me to figure it out. If you want help, you're going to have to do a bit more than that.

Comment: Thought I linked the page, my bad. PDF page 46. Questions on PDF page 42, Question 3

Comment: Look at page 34.  The answer to 5.2(3) indicates that under these operations "the set $V$ is not a vector space"  (Key word:  *not*.)

Comment: The PDF page 46 only says "Answers to odd numbered exercises" with no elaboration. Nothing there says "yes" or "no". The page numbered 46 within the document is blank.

Comment: @SelrachDunbar the question states only 2 axioms fail to hold: 7 and 8.

Comment: The question says it is **NOT** a vector space and asks you to identify which axioms fail. Do try to read carefully; it's likely to save everyone a lot of time.

Comment: The fact that $(-1)(u,v)$ is the additive inverse of $(u,v)$ is **not** an axiom, it is a *consequence* of the axioms. Check the axioms carefully. As I noted, there *is* an additive inverse for $(u,v)$: it is $(-u-2,-v-2)$.

Comment: Your post says you know it **is** a vector space, so you did not read carefully **something**: either this post, or the book. I'm wagering the latter, since you doubled down on the claim in comments. And again: there **is** an identity: you already found it. There **are** additive inverses: they just aren't of the form $(-1)(u,v)$. The additive inverse of $(u,v)$ under this operation is $(-u-2,-v-2)$. I've said it three times now. Did you read it any of them?

Comment: If you see question 1 & answers, Axioms 3 and 4, additive inverse and additive identity are considered axioms, so you are wrong.

Comment: I'm not wrong. This operation **has** an additive identity: it is $(-1,-1)$. This operation **has** additive inverses: the additive inverse of $(u,v)$ is $(-u-2,-v-2)$: see: $(u,v)+(-u-2,-v-2) = (u-u-2+1,v-v-2+1) = (-1,-1)$, the additive identity. Your error is to think that the additive inverse must be given as the result of multiplying the scalar $-1$ with the vector $(u,v)$. *That is not an axiom*.

Comment: Understand now, thank you.

Comment: Note that the axiom uses $-\mathbf{x}$, not $(-1)\mathbf{x}$. $-\mathbf{x}$ is just the name of the vector. That $-\mathbf{x} = (-1)\cdot\mathbf{x}$ is a **theorem**, not an axiom.